# MS SQL Server 2012: network access configuration not working

Tags: sql-server, configuration, sql-server-2012, network-protocols, server-configuration

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express with Advanced Services on Windows 7 64-bit.
During installation I chose to configure the SQL Server instance as the "Default instance",
and as a result I am able to connect to it using TCP/IT by specifying either "localhost",
"(local)", "MyComputerName", or "." in the "Server name:" field in Microsoft SQL Server 
Management Studio (in each case the connection shows up on the left-hand column of
SQL Server Management Studio as "SQL Server 11.0.3128 - MyComputerName\MyUserName".
However when I access the Services window from the Control Panel's Administration Tools,
I can see that the installed SQL Server instance is running using the connection name
"NT Service\MSSQLSERVER". This corresponds to the "Instance ID: MSSQLSERVER"
which appeared automatically during installation when I chose "Default instance".
What I would like to ask is:

Given this configuration, why can't I connect by specifying MSSQLSERVER or alternatively
NT Service\MSSQLSERVER in the server name field in SQL Server Management Studio? How can
I get this alternative connection mechanism to work (without recreating a new SQL Server instance)?

Perhaps I don't fully understand how connections, connection strings, and connection types
work under Winodows, and what the underlying Windows-specific connection protocols are.
Perhaps someone can point these details out and sort out any confusing issues related
to these which arise when someone know about TCP/IP but not so much about proprietary
Windows network protocols.

Thanks.

Comment: While MS SQL Server 2012 LocalDB is a separate executable, specifying (localdb)\v11.0 as the connection string is not working either despite the fact that I checked the checkbox to install LocalDB during installation. Why is this? Thanks.

Comment: OK, not sure now, I didn't even reboot my system, but now specifying (LocalDb)\v11.0 as the server name when connecting is working for me now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused between the two connection authentication types:

- Windows authentication
- SQL server authentication

to access SQL server remotely you will have to create a SQL user account or to access it from a
windows authenticated user.

- Windows authentication:
  Let's say you have a domain controller that has a group that called MSSQL_USERS, then you'll have to add this group in the SQL server and give the right access to it, after that you can connect to sql server remotely using windows authentication sure after logging to the Windows by a user that belongs to that group.
- SQL server authentication: MS SQL server gives you the possibility to create users with passwords and give them access to the needed access, databases, tasks...Create an account on an SQL server instance with a password will give you the access to connect to that instance.

now if your instance called "MSSQLSERVER" so you must put it after the server name\IP address
e.g: 192.168.3.9\MSSQLSERVER
or SQL_SERVER\MSSQLSERVER

if you are working locally it is not necessary to put the server name.
if the server name didn't work then you may have an issue with your DNS, putting the IP address is always safer and will solve this kind of problems.

---

To enable the network connection to the server you gonna have to enable the remote connections to the server from :

1- right click on the server > go to properties

2- go to connections and enable the remote connections

During setup, you must select an authentication mode for the Database Engine. There are two possible modes: Windows Authentication mode and mixed mode, the MIXED mode that enables you to connect to SQL server by both types SQL authentication and windows authentication, if that option wasn't in the setup program you have, then you should go to the

server properties>security tab>server authentication

also when you install MS SQL server you can assign the password for the "sa" user which is the SQL server administrator, but that will be enabled only when mixed mode is enabled because the windows authentication mode will disable the SQL server authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I am using Windows Authentication. However, now that you have pointed out this syntax, I am trying to connect locally on Windows 7 Home Premium by specifying localhost\MSSQLSERVER or alternatively 127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER or alternatively 192.168.1.66\MSSQLSERVER (using the IP address assigned to my box by the router). Unfortunately, none of them works. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? I want to connect by specifying both the host and the server instance, as I am learning. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you have not explained how come I cannot connect to the SQL Server LocalDB instance.

Comment: And I would also like to know: when installing SQL Server, my options were to configure authentication to the database engine either using Windows authentication, or using Windows authentication + SQL Server authentication. You seem to point out that it is possible to use SQL Server authentication without using Windows authentication. How would one configure that, given that the installation program does not offer this possibility? Thanks.

Comment: I've also installed a nondefault instance called SQLEXPRESS (the default), and can access it as MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS . However I can't seem to be able to access the default server in this way. If anyone knows why, then please let me know.

Comment: Please see my additions

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the update. When I installed SQL Server 2012 I only enabled Windows Authentication (did not configure mixed mode so cannot authenticate using SQL Server Authentication as an alternative). This also meant that with my setup I could not even log in with the default system administrator username (sa) and password (which by default is the blank password). Once logged in I can see by right-clicking on the server instance and selecting Properties -> Connections that the "Allow remote connections to this server" checkbox is checked; this seems to be the default for all installations.

Comment: Also in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, once I log in, when I right click on the SQL Server instance and select Properties and then Click on the Security tab, I can change the server authentication from Windows Authentication to SQL Server Authentication and Windows Authentication. I've then restarted SQL Server. Once that was done I still couldn't log in using SQL Server authentication and user sa though. Logging in via windows authentication, expanding the Security folder under the instance, then expanding the Logins folder, and then sa, I can see that...

Comment: I can see that, strangely, the sa password is not blank. So I changed it and set it to something else, and logged out. However when I tried to log back in using sql server authentication, username sa, password my password, and server name MyComputerName\MSSQLSERVER, it still hangs and then tells me that the server could not be found or is not accessible. Please help me use SQL Server authentication with my default instance as it's not working for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is strange, but there still a lot of things that may cause the issue:
1- First of all just disable the firewalls/antiviruses you have.
2- Be sure that from server properties you are configuring the same instance that you are trying to login not another one, just a suggestion you can remove all instances you have and leave only one..

Comment: 3- The default instance name is not the same in all MS SQL server versions, the user may become confused with the current instance name, so it will be better if you specify the instance name and don't leave it blank or default.
4- The server name will be IP_Address\Instance_Name, this is safer than Computer_Name\Instance_Name.
5- If you didn't know the current instance you have you can get it from the system services like you did before.

Comment: 6- When you install SQL server the service account must be : "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
7- If you are configuring an installed instance, and you changed the mode to be mixed, you must be sure that the SQL server user you want to use is Granted and Enabled!!! and that must be configured from the right click on the user then properties, be sure that it is enabled and granted.
I hope that I helped you, if that all didn't work then the instance name or the ip address you are using is wrong..

Comment: I hope my answer helped you!

Answer (score 0):

For me -  I had multiple SQL server instances installed from past and I was trying to check in older version's configuration manager. When I tried opening "SQLSERVERMANAGER10.msc" in Win+R which is a right service for SQL Server 2008 it worked for me.

If you are trying to further setup your port 1433 on localhost - try following -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177440.aspx